# how to parse a file.html with jsoup in java

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

i have file.html,i want to open it and extract the links with jsoup library and show those links in the out put of my program
how can i use this library to do this???

```
               String html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head>"
                + "<body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p></body></html>";
                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
```

i want to do some thing like that,i want that file.html as String and extract the links of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you the links are in the  section, you'd do...

`Element body = Document.body()`

This would then give you an element object, you could then use...

`body.getElementsByAttribute("href");`

which would return you a list of Element of objects of all the links.